# Check syntax of R script without running it

Tags: r

After making changes to a R script, is there a way to check its syntax by running a command, before running the R script itself?

Comment: Yes, check out the `lintr` package. This allows `lint("myscript.R")`, which will pick up syntax errors (though obviously not logical errors) without actually running the code.

Answer (score 6):

Base R has `parse` which will parse a script without running it.

```
parse("myscript.R")
```

The codetools package, which comes with R, has `checkUsage` and `checkUsagePackage` to check single functions and packages respectively.

Answer (score 3):

There is `lint()` from the `lint` package:

```r
lintr::lint("tets.r")
#> tets.r:1:6: style: Place a space before left parenthesis, except in a function call.
#> is.na(((NA))
#>      ^
#> tets.r:1:12: error: unexpected end of input
#> is.na(((NA))
#>            ^
```

The tested file contains only this wrong code

```
is.na(((NA))
```

You can customise what `lint()` checks. By default, it is quite noisy about code style (which is the main reason I use it).

Answer (score 0):

From within an R console/REPL session, you can use the builtin [base](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base)'s [parse](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/parse) function:

```
$ R

> parse("hello.r")
expression(cat("Hello, World!\n"))

> parse("broken.r")
Error in parse("broken.r") : broken.r:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: cat("Hello, World!\n"
   ^
```

The [parse](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/parse) function throws an error in case it fails to parse.  A limitation here is that it will only detect parse errors, but not for example references to undefined functions.

#### Directly from the command line

You can also check parsing directly from the command line by using [Rscript](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/topics/Rscript)'s `-e` option to call [parse](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/parse):

```sh
$ Rscript -e 'parse("hello.r")'
expression(cat("Hello, World!\n"))

$ Rscript -e 'parse("broken.r")'
Error in parse("broken.r") : broken.r:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: cat("Hello, World!\n"
   ^
Execution halted
```

A nice result of this is that [Rscript](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/topics/Rscript) returns successfully (no exit code) when the parse works and
it returns an error code when the parse fails.  So you can use your shell's `||` and `&&` operators as usual or other forms of error detection (`set -e`).

### Custom parsing script

You can also create a custom script that wraps everything nicely:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Rparse: checks whether R scripts parse successfully
#
# usage: Rscript script.r
# usage: Rscript file1.r file2.r file3.r ...
set -e
for file in "$@"
do
    Rscript -e "parse(\"$file\")"
done
```

Place the script in a folder pointed by your `$PATH` variable and use it to check your R files as follows:

```
$ Rparse hello.r broken.r 
expression(cat("Hello, World!\n"))
Error in parse("broken.r") : broken.r:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: cat("Hello, World!\n"
   ^
Execution halted
```

Here I am using `bash` as a reference language but there's nothing impeding alternatives to be built for other shells including Windows' ".bat" files or even an R script!

(Other answers already address the question quite nicely, but I wanted to document some additional possibilities in a more complete answer.)